# How to register a Hibernate Empty Interceptor in Spring's applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, hibernate

How do I easily hook up a Hibernate EmptyInterceptor (an Audit Interceptor) in a Spring app's applicationContext.xml?

No annotations are supported, this is an older Spring app.

My Hibernate Empty Interceptor is

```
public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("onDelete intercepted");
        super.onDelete(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("onFlushDirty intercepted");
        return super.onFlushDirty(entity, id, currentState, previousState, propertyNames, types);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {       
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("onSave intercepted");
        return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">


<beans>

     <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${jdbc.datasource}" />
 </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/2323-how-to-use-an-hibernate-interceptor-with-spring

Answer (score 1):

The following worked. Thanks for the tip

```
<!-- First define the bean -->
<bean id="auditInterceptor" class="mypackage.AuditInterceptor" />

<!-- Now add entityInterceptor property in sessionFactory Bean, referring to this bean -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor" />
```